# Store .vuepress folder in another directory

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

Is there a way to configure **vuepress** to look for the folder `.vuepress` somewhere else than default `/docs`?

Comment: Hello from 2019--the new VuePress documentation site annoyingly doesn't have any way to navigate to the page, but they explain the recommended directory structure [here](https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/directory-structure.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** VuePress 1.5.0 now only reads from `docs/.vuepress`, so the workaround below no longer works. However, another possible (less elegant) workaround is to symlink the `docs/.vuepress` to the desired location (tested on macOS Catalina).

For example, you could symlink it to `<projectRoot>/.vuepress` on macOS with:

```sh
mkdir .vuepress docs
cd docs
ln -s ../.vuepress
```

---

As of VuePress 0.12.0, there's no specific configuration to set the location of `.vuepress/`. VuePress always looks for `.vuepress/` in the target directory (`docs/`) and the immediate parent directory. If not found, VuePress creates `.vuepress/` in the parent directory of `docs/`.

If your objective is to prevent the creation of `docs/.vuepress/` and you didn't mind `.vuepress/` in the parent directory of `docs/`:

1. Create `.vuepress/config.js` in the parent directory of `docs/`.
2. Edit that file to contain the following config:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     dest: 'foo' // desired path to VuePress output
   }
   ```
3. Run `vuepress build` in the parent directory of `docs/`.

The result of the above config is to create a directory `foo/` with the VuePress static site output:

```
$ vuepress build

WAIT  Extracting site metadata...
[2:20:45 AM] Compiling Client
[2:20:45 AM] Compiling Server
(node:47073) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
[2:20:48 AM] Compiled Server in 3s
[2:20:50 AM] Compiled Client in 5s
WAIT  Rendering static HTML...

DONE  Success! Generated static files in foo.
```

Comment: Unfortunately the parent level .vuepress does not seem to work any more. VuePress 1.5.0 demands the configuration to be in docs/.vuepress/config.js

Comment: @akauppi Thanks for the update! A simple workaround would be to symlink `.vuepress` so that `docs/.vuepress` links to the desired location.

Comment: I tried that, but then changed my mind. My intention is to keep my repo as approachable for visitors as possible, and symlinks often work against that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is. In 2018, the author [has stated](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/105#issuecomment-382013166):

> I don't see practical value in this except for personal preference, so probably not.